# 301 redirect ONLY for .asp and not .aspx

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect every request that ends in `.asp` to the homepage. However, I also have `.aspx` requests that I am redirecting to specific pages on the site, so I do not want this rule to affect the `.aspx` requests.

I currently am using this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 (.*)\.asp http://mywebsite.com
```

It does redirect .asp to the homepage, but now it's also redirecting all the .aspx requests to the homepage as well and ignoring my specific rules in place for them.

Is there a way to ONLY target `.asp`, or specifically UNtarget `.aspx` in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `$` in your regex:

```
RedirectMatch 301 (.*)\.asp$ http://mywebsite.com
```

The `$` indicates the end of the match, so it will match `.asp` but *not* `.aspx`.